# PHP and Tumblr API - autopost

Tags: php, api, tumblr

I am playing with Tumblr API and trying to build an autoposter. I have a script that I run, then I am  as a user asked for allowing my Tumblr app and then I am authenticated => a post is posted.

I've tried to run this script by CRON, byt it doesn't work. Why?
My though why - when I run the script, I am always asked for confirmation that I allow an access of my Tumblr app to my blog...

What do you think? Could be this the problem? Also, is there any way how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Hi, I've done some further work, actually I can post on tumblr, automatically, the only issue is when you want to post large files, take a look here and if you want to contribute, good: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36747697/oauth-signature-creation-issue-with-php

Answer (score 1):

If any script requires user interaction it will not work when ran via cron. Cron has no idea how to answer for you. Tumblr uses oauth for authentication and it probably making you go through the oauth flow every time that you try to post. If you have the correct request token and request token secret you can make posts without manually authorizing your application. Read up on Tumblr's api docs, the oauth flow, and look for a library made to work with Tumblr's api.

Comment: thank you for your response. This is what makes me a bit confused - the correct `request token` and `request token secret`. Where/how can I get them? `$request_token = $tum_oauth->getRequestToken($callback_url);` - this is the way how I am getting them in the code. So - should I note these tokens and set up the "hardly" into the code as the constants?